# Magento 2 Export & Import CMS Blocks and CMS Pages

Tags: magento2, blocks, export, cms-pages

How to Export and Import CMS Pages and Static blocks ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [MSP/CmsImportExport](https://github.com/magespecialist/m2-MSP_CmsImportExport).

However the db tables involved are:

- `cms_block`
- `cms_block_store`
- `cms_page`
- `cms_page_store`

Answer (score 1):

The module `Magento_CmsSampleData` is using a similar system for the **import**, you can use it to make your own system.

at `app/code/Magento/CmsSampleData/composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "magento/module-cms-sample-data",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6",
        "magento/module-cms": "101.1.*",
        "magento/module-sample-data": "100.2.*",
        "magento/module-theme-sample-data": "100.2.*",
        "magento/sample-data-media": "100.2.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "100.2.0-dev",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\CmsSampleData\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

For reference, take a look at the [Github repository of the module](https://github.com/magento/magento2-sample-data/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/CmsSampleData/composer.json).

Answer (score 0):

You can manually export/import the cms_block and cms_page's database tables using `mysqldump` or `phpmyadmin`.

All the data you need should be in those two tables.